# Variable reassignment with chained booleans or ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, boolean-expression

**To clarify:**
*This is purely for experimental purposes, to learn the quirks, odds and ends of a new (to me) language. I would of course write it readable if I ever were to share this code with anyone else. :-)*

---

I have a function `someFunction(x)`, and two global variables:

```js
let m = 2;
let e = 5;
```

Inside the function, I want to check if `x == m`. If this is true, I'd like to pass `m` to a side function call (`sideFunction(m)`), then reassign `x` to `e` to complete `someFunction`.

This ***does*** work as expected:

```js
const someFunction = x => {
    if (x == m) {
        sideFunction(m);
        x = e;
    }
    doOtherStuffWith(x);
}
```

However, I'd like to shorten it, preferably to one line. This is also to understand more about ternaries and/or boolean chaining.

I have tried these two methods:

```js
// Boolean chaining
const someFunction = x => {
    x == m && sideFunction(m) && (function () {x = e})();
    doOtherStuffWith(x);
}
```

This does ***not*** work, presumably because the assignment `x = e` only applies to the `x` in the local scope of the inner, anonymous function...?

```js
// Ternary operator
const someFunction = x => {
    x = (x == m && sideFunction(m)) ? e : x;
    doOtherStuffWith(x);
}
```

This does ***not*** work, presumably because `sideFunction(m)` doesn't actually get called, for some reason...?

How can I fix these to make them work?
Alternatively, are there other, elegant ways to perform this check/call/reassignment without a full multi-line `if` block?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `sideFunction` return? Looks like a void function, in which case it would evaluate to `false`...

Comment: "*This does not work, presumably because the assignment x = e only applies to the x in the local scope of the inner, anonymous function...?*" or presumably because `someFunction` returns a falsy value. Likely `undefined` (if it doesn't have an explicit `return`). I don't see what is the need to shorten it. You tried and see where it brought you - how much time and typing did you spend on this question? Does it make up for the few characters you might save?

Comment: Keeping it short: don't make this one line.

Comment: @fredrik Woah, I didn't even think about that. Thank you!

Comment: @VLAZ I'm experimenting to learn how the language work. I would never write it this way in a production environment. :-) Thank you anyway!

Comment: There's no need to experiment to know how the language works - just read the specification. It's more reliable...

Comment: I did, and always do, read the documentation. Unfortunately, no documentation can cover all use cases. I believe that experimenting, trying and failing will always be a necessary part of learning any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
x == m && sideFunction(m) && (function () {x = e})();
```

is that `&&` evaluates left-to-right, and will stop as soon as the first falsey value is found. Unless `sideFunction` returns something explicitly truthy, the third IIFE:

```
(function () {x = e})()
```

will never run, resulting in `x` never being reassigned.

`x` is local in that function. If you can get the function to run, it will reassign `x` as desired.

You could use the comma operator:

```
x == m && (sideFunction(m), x = e);
```

---

Similarly

```
x = (x == m && sideFunction(m)) ? e : x;
```

won't work because `sideFunction` would have to return something truthy for the left side of the conditional to evaluate truthily - otherwise, `x` will be assigned to `x`, no change.

---

All this said - I'd highly recommend not doing any of these. Your first approach is much more readable, and readability is much more important than line conservation.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a compound expression with a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and do not care about the result value of `sideFunction`.

```
const fn = x => (x == m && (sideFunction(m), x = e), doOtherStuffWith(x));
```

Comment: For the record, this is four (4) characters shorter than what OP has. If we discount the contiguous whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator `,` can be used to chain expressions and return the last one e.g.,

```js
var x = (1 + 2, 10 + 2, 100 + 2);
x;
//=> 102
```

We can use it to evaluate `sideFunction(m)` and return `e`: `(sideFunction(m), e)`.

Since you always want to execute `doOtherStuffWith` you only need to work out whether to give it `e` or the original `x`:

```js
const someFunction = x => doOtherStuffWith(x == m ? (sideFunction(m), e) : x);
```